# using python regex to extract certain URLs from text

Tags: python, regex, url

So I have the HTML from an NPR page, and I want to use regex to extract just certain URLs for me (these call the URLs to specific stories nested within the page). The actual links appear in the text (retrieved manually) as:

```
<a href="http://www.npr.org/blogs/parallels/2014/11/11/363018388/how-the-islamic-state-wages-its-propaganda-war">
<a href="http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2014/11/11/363309020/asked-to-stop-praying-alaska-school-won-t-host-state-tournament">
<a href="http://www.npr.org/2014/11/11/362817642/a-marines-parents-story-their-memories-that-you-should-hear">
<a href="http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2014/11/11/363288744/comets-rugged-landscape-makes-landing-a-roll-of-the-dice">
<a href="http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2014/11/11/363293514/for-dyslexics-a-font-and-a-dictionary-that-are-meant-to-help">
```

obviously, I cannot to continue to use manual retrieval if I want to be able to use this on a consistent basis. So far, I have this code:

```
import nltk
import re

f = open("/Users/shannonmcgregor/Desktop/npr.txt")
npr_lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

I have this code to grab everything between (

```
for line in npr_lines:
re.findall('<a href="?\'?([^"\'>]*)', line)
```

But that grabs all urls. I tried adding something like:

```
(parallels|thetwo-way|a-marines)
```

but that returns nothing. So what am I doing wrong? How I combine the larger URL stripper with these specific words that target the given URLs?

Please and thank you :)

Comment: What's your input and expected output?

Comment: Use an HTML parser instead, http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: could you post the contents of `/Users/shannonmcgregor/Desktop/npr.txt` file along with the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.search` function to match the regex in the line and prints the line if it matches as

```
>>> file  = open('/Users/shannonmcgregor/Desktop/npr.txt', 'r')
>>> for line in file:
...     if re.search('<a href=[^>]*(parallels|thetwo-way|a-marines)', line):
...             print line
```

will give an output as

```
<a href="http://www.npr.org/blogs/parallels/2014/11/11/363018388/how-the-islamic-state-wages-its-propaganda-war">
<a href="http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2014/11/11/363309020/asked-to-stop-praying-alaska-school-won-t-host-state-tournament">
<a href="http://www.npr.org/2014/11/11/362817642/a-marines-parents-story-their-memories-that-you-should-hear">
<a href="http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2014/11/11/363288744/comets-rugged-landscape-makes-landing-a-roll-of-the-dice">
<a href="http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2014/11/11/363293514/for-dyslexics-a-font-and-a-dictionary-that-are-meant-to-help">
```

Answer (score 2):

Through a tool which is specially designed for parsing `html` and `xml` files [[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)],

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> s = """<a href="http://www.npr.org/blogs/parallels/2014/11/11/363018388/how-the-islamic-state-wages-its-propaganda-war">
<a href="http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2014/11/11/363309020/asked-to-stop-praying-alaska-school-won-t-host-state-tournament">
<a href="http://www.npr.org/2014/11/11/362817642/a-marines-parents-story-their-memories-that-you-should-hear">
<a href="http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2014/11/11/363288744/comets-rugged-landscape-makes-landing-a-roll-of-the-dice">
<a href="http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2014/11/11/363293514/for-dyslexics-a-font-and-a-dictionary-that-are-meant-to-help">"""
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s) # or pass the file directly into BS like >>> soup = BeautifulSoup(open('/Users/shannonmcgregor/Desktop/npr.txt'))
>>> atag = soup.find_all('a')
>>> links = [i['href'] for i in atag]
>>> import re
>>> for i in links:
        if re.match(r'.*(parallels|thetwo-way|a-marines).*', i):
            print(i)


http://www.npr.org/blogs/parallels/2014/11/11/363018388/how-the-islamic-state-wages-its-propaganda-war
http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2014/11/11/363309020/asked-to-stop-praying-alaska-school-won-t-host-state-tournament
http://www.npr.org/2014/11/11/362817642/a-marines-parents-story-their-memories-that-you-should-hear
http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2014/11/11/363288744/comets-rugged-landscape-makes-landing-a-roll-of-the-dice
http://www.npr.org/blogs/thetwo-way/2014/11/11/363293514/for-dyslexics-a-font-and-a-dictionary-that-are-meant-to-help
```

Comment: `re.match(r'.*(parallels|thetwo-way|a-marines).*', i)` is better spelt `re.search(r'parallels|thetwo-way|a-marines', i)` in this case

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a **[lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**:

```
<a href="?\'?((?=[^"\'>]*(?:thetwo\-way|parallels|a\-marines))[^"\'>]+)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/OyrP6Pml2hADERag)