# using python regex to extract clean URLs

Tags: python, regex

Thanks! I used @nu11p01n73R 's answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012594/using-python-regex-to-extract-certain-urls-from-text/27021993#27021993), and I got mostly the URLS, but still some some extra "noise" at the beginning and end. I'm ideally looking for it to just print the URL - http://something.some - so the regex would remove the `<a herf="` at the beginning of the URL and remove `" data-metrics='{"action" : "Click Story 2"}'>` at the end of it. I tried modifying the expression to get that, but I'm having trouble that the URL begins and ends with a " - I think that is messing up me regex. Any suggestions?

URLs are embedded like this in .txt file:

```
<a href="http://www.npr.org/blogs/parallels/2014/11/11/363018388/how-the-islamic-state-wages-its-propaganda-war" data-metrics='{"action":"Click Story 1"}' >
```

I'd love the output to be:

```
http://www.npr.org/blogs/parallels/2014/11/11/363018388/how-the-islamic-state-wages-its-propaganda-war
```

Most recent code I used was:

```
file  = open("/Users/shannonmcgregor/Desktop/npr.txt", 'r')
for line in file:
    if re.search('<a href=[^>]*(islamic|praying|marines|comets|dyslexics)', line):
        print line
```

But this returns, for example:

```
<a href="http://www.npr.org/blogs/parallels/2014/11/11/363018388/how-the-islamic-state-wages-its-propaganda-war" data-metrics='{"action":"Click Story 1"}' >
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj - nothing wrong with beautiful soup (it's beautiful), just trying to use regex because I need to get more comfortable with them and this helps with that.

Comment: ok, could you post an example along with expected output?

Comment: Regex is not a suitable tool for HTML parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.findall` function to extract the content as

```
file  = open("/Users/shannonmcgregor/Desktop/npr.txt", 'r')
for line in file:
    if re.search('<a href=[^>]*(islamic|praying|marines|comets|dyslexics)', line):
        print re.findall(r'(?<=")[^"]*(?=")', line)[0]
```

will produce an output as

```
http://www.npr.org/blogs/parallels/2014/11/11/363018388/how-the-islamic-state-wages-its-propaganda-war
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not the right tool to parse html files. Because you intend, i post this solution.

```
>>> import re
>>> file  = open("/Users/shannonmcgregor/Desktop/npr.txt", 'r')
>>> for i in file:
        if re.search('<a href="[^>"]*(islamic|praying|marines|comets|dyslexics)', i):
            i = re.sub(r'^.*?<a href="([^"]*)".*', r'\1', i)
            print(i)
```

**OR**

```
>>> for i in file:
        if re.search('<a href="[^>"]*(islamic|praying|marines|comets|dyslexics)', i):
            print(re.search(r'^.*?<a href="([^"]*)".*', i).group(1))
```

Comment: why not just use group instead of sub

Comment: Yes. That is what I means.